# Count the occurence of a particular digit in a range of number

Tags: c++, debugging

I was trying to count the number of digit `2` in an range of number (say `2-22`, the answer would be `6: 2,12,20,21,22 as 22` contribute twice). This is the code that I came up with, yet it fails to run after value input. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int lowerbound,upperbound,sum=0;
    int nofNum(int num);
    scanf("%d %d",&lowerbound,&upperbound);
    for (int i=lowerbound;i<=upperbound;++i){
        sum+=nofNum(i);
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
int nofNum(int num){
    int count=0;
    while(num!=0){
        if (num%10==2){
            count++;
            num/=10;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What type of error are you getting ?

Comment: In your nofNum function, num will never be equal to 0 which will result in an infinite loop

Comment: btw there a better ways to solve this problem than brute force. I mean after all integer numbers arent that unpredictable (eg. in first approximation every 10th number has a `2`)

Comment: @user463035818 i think this is meant as an excercise. There is no actual problem with any importance.

Comment: @Gladaed imho especially for exercises one shouldnt allow obvious inefficiencies, otherwise the learning effect is the opposite of what it should be

Comment: @user463035818 premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @Gladaed it isnt premature to use a O(n) when there exists a O(1) solution.

Comment: @user463035818 but the O(1) takes way more human time. This is a ressource aswell.

Comment: @Gladaed its like teaching that summing up integers up to n can be implemented by using a loop. Of course you can use a loop, but no real program should use a loop to do that, so there is no point in using it as an excercise

Comment: You probably want to `num /= 10;` on every iteration, not just those where `num%10==2` (i.e. move the assignment out of the `if` block - or write the loop as `for (count = 0;  num;  num/=10) count += num % 10 == 2;` to be clearer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using c not c++. Your mistake is that nofNum wasn't declared before you used it. It has to be declared before the line you use it.

```
int nofNum(int num);
```

would declare it.
You will still need to implement it, which you allready did.

alternatively you can move the implementation st. it is above main, where you used it.

EDIT: i just saw you declared it inside main, which is uncommon at best. you really should not do that.

EDIT2:
    you messed up that if statement in numOf

```
int nofNum(int num){
int count=0;
while(num!=0){
    if (num%10==2){
        count++;
    }
    num/=10; // may not be inside if, since num would not be adjusted 
             // if the last digit isnt a 2
}
return count;
}
```

EDIT3: 
you can use input and output streams in c++ to replace scanf and printf:

```
scanf("%d %d",&lowerbound,&upperbound);
```

becomes

```
std::cin >> lowerbound >> upperbound;
```

and

```
printf("%d",sum);
```

becomes

```
std::cout << sum << std::endl;
```

Edit4:

suggested form:

```
// declarations - this is what would belong to the *.h file later on.
int nofNum(int num);
```

followed by

```
int nofNum(int num) { /*implementation*/ }
int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[]) { /*implementation*/ }
```

or

```
// this is valid because we allready heard of nofNum through declaration
int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[]) { /*implementation*/ } 
int nofNum(int num) { /*implementation*/ }
```

the upper form doesn't require the declarations because each function allready is implemented before you use them, therefore the compiler allready knows what nofNum is supposed to be.

Comment: "_you are using c not c++._" How can he be using C, when the code contains such code as `using namespace std;`?

Comment: he could remove that and would be left with working code. This is the only part thats c++. He didn't utilize anything that wasn't allready there in c

Comment: If the code is meant to be compiled with C++ compiler, it is, effectively, C++ (Note: headers included, too, doesn't exist in C). Yes, one can write C-like code with C++, but the function names isn't the only difference between code compiled with C, and C++ compilers.

Comment: Thanks! Moving num/=10 solved the problem. And another few questions: Why do you recommend cin/cout over scanf/printf? My professor said the latter is suppose to be faster. And where is a better position to place int nofNum(int num) ?

Comment: @Huan I prefer outstreams due to their good legibility. Performance rarely is important. (premature optimization is the root of all evil) That being said if you are comfortable with printf and scanf  feel free to use them. Outstreams just have the advantage that you can define operators such that eg. vectors can be print easyly. If you use them look up std::endl ! it is very much not the same as '\n' and can significantly slow down output, as it flushes the stream.